# How to use Arzelà-Ascoli here?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, arzela-ascoli

The problem is

> Suppose $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a bounded open set. Consider the initial-boundary value problem $$\begin{cases}
>  \partial_{t}u(x,t)-\Delta u(x,t)=0 & \text{in}\ \Omega\times(0,\infty)\\
>  u=u_{0} & \text{on}\ \Omega\times\{0\}\\
>  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\nu}u(x,t)=0 & \text{on}\ \partial\Omega\times(0,\infty).\\
>  \end{cases}$$
> And assume the first and second order derivatives of its solution $u$ exist in $\overline{\Omega}\times[0,\infty)$. Then use Arzelà-Ascoli to show $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\lvert\nabla u(x,t)\rvert=0\quad \forall\,x\in\Omega.$$

I tried using the energy method. Let $$E(t)=\int_{\Omega}u^{2}(x,t)\,dx.$$It is easy to see $E’(t)\leq0$ and $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}E’(t)=0$. But I’m confused how to find a sequence to use the theorem. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: It's definitely not true that your $ E(t) $ approaches zero at $ t \rightarrow \infty $.  Consider $ \Omega = [0,1] $, $ u_0(x) \equiv 1 $.   Then the solution to this is $ u(x,t) = 1 $.  So maybe check your "easy to see" claim.

Comment: @JakeMirra I claim that $E’$ approaches zero.

Comment: Given that $E'(t) = -\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u(x,t)|^2 dx$, doesn't $E'(t) \to 0$ directly prove the conclusion (because $u$ is continuous)? I'm not fully sure that Arzela-Ascoli is needed here.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you prove that $\lim_{t \to \infty} E'(t) = 0$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I think $E’(t)\to 0$ just implies the conclusion for a.e. $x\in\Omega$. And I proved $\lim_{t\to\infty}E’(t)=0$ by a contradiction.

Comment: @mio But $\nabla u$ is continuous on $\Omega$, so the a.e. becomes an equality everywhere i.e. for all $x \in \Omega$... oh, right, I see , it's not obvious because there's a limit as $t\to \infty$ involved. Nevertheless, I believe that some regularity of $\nabla u$ will do the job.

Comment: I might have an idea. I’ll write an answer later…

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\lvert\nabla u(x,t)\rvert\neq0$, then there exists a sequence $(t_{n})_{n}$ and a constant $\alpha>0$ such that $t_{n}\rightarrow\infty$ and $\lVert\nabla u(x,t_{n})\rVert_{L^{\infty}}\geq\alpha,\ n\rightarrow\infty$. Set $u_{n}(x)=\lvert\nabla u(x,t_{n})\rvert$. Since the second order derivative of $u$ exists on $\overline{\Omega}\times[0,\infty)$, we know $u_{n}$ is continuous on the compact set $\overline{\Omega}$. Moreover, $\lvert\Delta u(x,t_n)\rvert=\lvert\partial_t u(x,t_n)\rvert$ is also uniformly bounded on $\overline{\Omega}$, thus $(u_n)$ is equi-continuous. Consequently, by Arzelar-Ascoli, there exists a subsequence $(t_{n_{k}})_{k}$ converges to a continuous function $g$ uniformly on $\overline{\Omega}$. But$$\int_{\Omega}g^{2}(x)\,dx=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega}\lvert\nabla u(x,t_{n_{k}})\rvert^{2}\,dx=0.$$So $g\equiv0$, a contradiction.

Is it right?

Comment: To prove equicontinuity, you would need to know that $\sup_n\|\nabla^2 u(\cdot,t_n)\|_\infty<\infty$.

Comment: @Gio67 Oh, and since $u$ is the solution of the PDE we have $\Delta u=\partial_t u$, then it is uniformly bounded since the second order derivative of $u$ exists. Is it right?

Comment: No, the set $\overline{\Omega}\times [0,\infty)$ is not compact, so even if the second order derivative exists and is continuous, you cannot conclude that it is uniformly bounded.

Comment: @Gio67 Is that means the conditions of the problem are not enough? Or am I still missing something…

Comment: I don’t know how to prove it with the conditions you have, but there might be some trick that I am not seeing. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: It’s my homework, I’ll ask my professor for some details next week. Thanks for your responses!